Working with COG in GDAL
I have worked with GDAL previously and USGS 1/9th arc second data many years ago before I became severely ill and had to give it up. I am now looking at resurrecting what I was doing.
The problem is that since I had been using GDAL things seemed to have changed A LOT, and I am now completely lost as to how to do what I want.
What I need is to be able to download a block of 1m DEM data as a GeoTiff to my local HD for processing, once I have that I should be able to pick up from where I left off and convert it to a 16 bit normalized Height map for importing into the game engine after ensuring there are no NaN values and ranging the data to have a minimum value > 2.
At this point though I don't even know how to get the GeoTiff to be able to process it, I used to just download them from the USGS but now all of their images appear to be black and white and not grey scale.

These training videos might be useful to you.
You can download 1 meter data from the USGS National Map.  Select the polygon option, draw a polygon around your area of interest, select the 1 meter option from the 3DEP group.  Choose the search product option.  The available data layers will appear and you can add them to your cart and download them.
Black & white?  The national map thumbnails are images of the elevation data and not hillshades of the data. Your area of interest might just be flat.
